# "App isn't installed" error on Android 4.4.2

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, whatsapp

Good evening,

I keep getting the error "App isn't installed" whenever I try to open Whatsapp from the Home screen in Android 4.4.2. When I look for it in Settings->Apps, Whatsapp is not displayed on the app list; however, the App Store tells me it's already installed. If I download the .apk, it says the app is already installed but doesn't let me update it or re-install. How can I completely delete Whatsapp in order to re-install it?

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall it from the My Apps section in the Play Store. Then reinstall it.